# grep netlist and cell name from file

Tags: unix, tcl, tclsh

Suppose, Directory `A` contains two files, `fileA` and `netlist.tcl`. Below is information of `fileA`

```
Source "netlist.tcl"
cell "chklist"
```

I want that when the user selects `fileA` in Combobox in GUI,
Automatically in `netlist` string field: - a real path of the `netlist.tcl` from `fileA` popup
and in `cell string` field:-cell name from `fileA` popup.

How to achieve the above result?
output:

```
A/netlist.tcl
chklist
```

Comment: @Dominique no no when user open gui from shell

Comment: This is just basic file I/O in Tcl.  
    - open the file for reading
    - read each line
    - parse the data you need and save into variables
    - close the file
    - display the desired text

Comment: @ChrisHeithoff CAN YOU PLS EXPLAIN WITH EXAMPLE?

Answer (score 1):

There's several ways to parse such a file. Here's one of the nicer ones with a *safe child* interpreter:

```
interp create -safe i
i alias Source netlistSource
i alias cell netlistCell

proc netlistSource {filename} {
    global fn
    set fn $filename
    return
}
proc netlistCell {cellname} {
    global cn
    set cn $cellname
    return
}

i invokehidden source "fileA"
interp delete i
```

That will store `netlist.tcl` in `fn` and `chklist` in `cn`. I'm not sure where the `A/` prefix comes from, so I've left that part out.

---

Real code might need more aliases setting up. I hope you can see how easy that is to do. Remember, the aliases are *called* in the child, but call into your nominated code in the parent interpreter; it's a bit like doing an OS system call but with much less overhead. (Safe interpreters have all commands that touch the OS disabled/hidden by default.)

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is just basic file I/O and string matching, then this would be a start.  You would just need to adapt this into whatever you're doing with the GUI.

```
# File I/O
set fp [open fileA "r"]
set lines [split [read $fp] "\n"]
close $fp

# Check lines for netlist and cell
foreach line $lines {
    if {[string match "Source*" $line]} {
        set netlist [lindex $line 1]
        if {[file exists $netlist]} {
            puts [file normalize "./$netlist"]
        }

    }

    if {[string match "cell*" $line]} {
        set cell [lindex $line 1]
        puts "$cell"
    }
}
```

There are multiple ways to do this kind of work.  regexes vs string matching.    opening the file in Tcl vs executing a system call to grep vs using the fileutil package...

There's nothing here that isn't covered in Tcl introduction, like https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Tcl+Tutorial+Index.   It would be helpful to understand what you've already tried.

Donal's previous answer using a safe interpreter is pretty cool too, if you understand what's happening.